single RAID0 Harddrive stalls when mounting
This is a cross post / repost from my linux/Unix question, after I didn't get any further comments/answers to the adittional data I gave:
Problem Description
We are using a Debian 12 Server with a Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 controller. Our harddrives are all set up with their own Virtual drive in RAID0. One of those hard drives was unable to mount after the last restart. When attempting to mount it, the console just "waits" indefinitely without completing the operation or giving any output. also trying to close/kill the console doesn't help.
Hard Drive Specifications

Western Digital 5TB Hard Drive (WD50NPZZ)

Troubleshooting Steps Taken
Below are the outputs from various checks I performed:

Device Identification:

Identified as /dev/sdd. Mounting /dev/sdd1 results in the stall.


df Output:

The device is obviously not mounted.


SMART Check:

sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd

smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.0-21-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD50NPZZ-00A9JT0
Serial Number:    WD-WXV2EA029SJF
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2be2d94f3
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    5,000,981,078,016 bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jun 10 17:29:14 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                ( 3060) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 348) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4900
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   066   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       24896
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       136
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   126   115   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     24725         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23465         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported


lsblk Output:
omitted all other (mounted) harddrives
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdd      8:48   0   4.5T  0 disk 
`-sdd1   8:49   0   4.5T  0 part
...


fdisk -l Output:
Disk /dev/sdd: 4.55 TiB, 5000981078016 bytes, 9767541168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD50NPZZ-00A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 38CFA2C8-1A78-4357-8F34-5BDDE5E6B498

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 9767540735 9767538688  4.5T Linux filesystem


Installing mega_cli
after I added all my info in the Post on Unix & Linux, i searched for days and found megacli as a command line interface to access the raidcontroller and harddrives directly.
running it ald in specting the suspicious harddrive gave me following output:
megacli -PDList -a0 Output:
(omitted non relevant harddrives)
Enclosure Device ID: 62
Slot Number: 7
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 13
WWN: 50014ee2be2d94f3
Sequence Number: 14
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 4.547 TB [0x24630d9b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 4.547 TB [0x24620d9b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 4.546 TB [0x246139800 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: JBOD
Device Firmware Level: 1A01
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221107000000
Connected Port Number: 7(path0) 
Inquiry Data:      WD-WXV2EA029SJFWDC WD50NPZZ-00A9JT0                    01.01A01
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :30C (86.00 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : Disabled
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No

Intresting note: the Device Firmware Level on all the other drives is 0001.
the Inquiry Data allways ends with the firmare level, except for this entry, where there is a 01.0 in front.
megacli -PhyErrorCounters -a0 Output:
(omitted not relevant drives, they all have 0;0;0;0 as their values)

Phy No: 7 
Invalid DWord Count           : 15 
Running Disparity Error Count : 3 
Loss of DWord Synch Count     : 3 
Phy Reset problem Count       : 0 

I do understand, that this harddrive seems to have a few problem, but I don't know, how to interpret it correctly.
So mybe someone can give me some insight in what propably happend to the device.


Request for Help
After multiple weeks of asking and researching, I got further step by step, but I am not sure how to move on at this point.
Does anyone have any ideas or tips on how to recover or repair this hard drive, or maybe get the data of it?
Adittional data:
most of the data below was requested in the commands of the old post, but didn't gave me any insight for the problem.
Filesystem Check

fsck /dev/sdd1 Output:
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
arch21: recovering journal
arch21: clean, 8029/152621056 files, 1122373603/1220942336 blocks



TestDisk Analysis

TestDisk:

Started TestDisk with sudo testdisk /dev/sds, selected the hard drive and [EFI GPT] partition map, and began analysis.
Initial output after the search:

TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdd - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 608001 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P Linux filesys. data         2048 9767540735 9767538688 [arch21]


<~20 newlines omitted>


Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
                P=Primary  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 5000 GB / 4657 GiB



parted -l output:
```
Model: ATA WDC WD50NPZZ-00A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 5001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  5001GB  5001GB  ext4         arch21


```

The full sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdd output:
```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdd: 9767541168 sectors, 4.5 TiB
Model: WDC WD50NPZZ-00A
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 38CFA2C8-1A78-4357-8F34-5BDDE5E6B498
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 9767541134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2413 sectors (1.2 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      9767540735   4.5 TiB     8300  arch21

``` 

output of sudo dmesg | grep -C 20 -e arch21 -e sdd1 -e sdd:
```
[616028.173215] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#231 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0

<omitted ~5000 lines with the same output except for [xxxxx.xxxxxx] and tag#xx>

[616256.020279] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#195 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
[616262.282547] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=362s
[616262.282558] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 CDB: Write(16) 8a 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[616262.282562] I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[616262.282616] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[616262.282709] EXT4-fs (sdd1): I/O error while writing superblock
[616262.282757] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mount failed
[616262.440133] sd 0:0:13:0: SCSI device is removed
[616262.491021] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[616262.491247] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[616262.492913] megaraid_sas 0000:0b:00.0: scanning for scsi0...
[616271.122959] scsi 0:0:13:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD50NPZZ-00A 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[616271.321365] sd 0:0:13:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[616271.323661] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] 9767541168 512-byte logical blocks: (5.00 TB/4.55 TiB)
[616271.323670] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[616271.424996] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[616271.425005] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 9b 00 10 08
[616271.426397] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[616271.536188]  sdd: sdd1
[616271.536460] sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[616279.922909]  sdd: sdd1
[616280.033973]  sdd: sdd1
[616494.154828]  sdd: sdd1
[616573.862696]  sdd: sdd1

```

output of journalctl -r:
```
Jun 13 14:06:51 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#214 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:51 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#213 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#212 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#211 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#210 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#209 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#208 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#207 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#206 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#205 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#204 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#203 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#202 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#201 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#200 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#199 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#198 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#197 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#196 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#195 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#194 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#193 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#192 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#255 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#254 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#253 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#252 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#251 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#250 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#249 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#248 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:50 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#247 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#246 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#244 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#243 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
Jun 13 14:06:49 kalsoy kernel: sd 0:0:13:0: [sdd] tag#242 BRCM Debug mfi stat 0x2d, data len requested/completed 0x1000/0x0
```


I'm unsure but I/O error, dev sdd  looks for me that this drive failed?

Never expect something to fail in some predictive way. The failure is by definition the unexpected behaviour; that includes "all seemingly all right, but doesn't work". Also this is not "RAID0". JBOD is different in that it's a direct access to the hardware, without creating any structures on disks.

I see, that the drive probably is dead. Just want to see if I miss anything or can recover it. (we have our backups in "biological" form - just reproduce the data).
@NikitaKipriyanov so the definition of JBOD I found was not really clear, but in general: multiple hard drives on a raid controller, all configured with RAID0. That Why I am using JBOD here.
the drives are each configured with their own virtual drive in the raid controller, defined as a single RAID0 drive.
It's no read pass-through. (when connecting the drive to my workstation its metadata is wrong, e.g. only ~600gb of space)

Then, it's wrong configuration. MegaRAID supports true JBOD, which you should have been using for this, instead of useless RAID0 layer.


Does anyone have any ideas or tips on how to recover or repair this hard drive, or maybe get the data of it?

Yes, replace the drive with brand new and restore from backup. This is what we do in case RAID doesn't help.
